# Make UIView stick to the top in a full width horizontal UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which contains full width images. I want a `UIView` on top of the `UIScrollView` at every point of time. Initially the output is correct, I am getting the `UIView` over the `UIScrollView`. But when I scroll right, the `UIView` is moving along with the first image to the left. How can I keep the `UIView` always on top ? Do I need to implement any other methodology ?

```
-(void)setSalonImagesScrollView{

int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [self.imageList count]; i++) {

    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIImageView *salImg =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin,0,320,194)];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageList[i]]];

    salImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    salImg.tag = i;
    [self.salonImgCarousel addSubview:salImg];
    [self.salonImgCarousel insertSubview:self.navSubView belowSubview:self.navSubView];

    x += salImg.frame.size.width;
}

self.salonImgCarousel.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, self.salonImgCarousel.frame.size.height);

[_salonImgCarousel setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[_salonImgCarousel setDelegate:self];}
```

Comment: add view on `self.view` not on scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, you are adding your imageView to the ScrollView. Everything you'll add to the ScrollView will be scrolled. You have to add your imageView to the View instead of ScrollView.

`[self.view addSubview:salImg];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)setSalonImagesScrollView{
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [self.imageList count]; i++) {

CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
UIImageView *salImg =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin,0,320,194)];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageList[i]]];

salImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
salImg.tag = i;
[self.view addSubview:salImg];
[self.salonImgCarousel insertSubview:self.navSubView belowSubview:self.navSubView];

x += salImg.frame.size.width;
}

self.salonImgCarousel.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, self.salonImgCarousel.frame.size.height);

[_salonImgCarousel setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[_salonImgCarousel setDelegate:self];}
```

and post your difficulty

Kind Regards

Koushik

Answer (score 0):

If you want `UIView` every time on top of your screen then best way is add `UIView` on `UIWindow`.

Ex.

```
[window addSubView:myView];
```

Also look at [How can access window in my view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760785/how-do-i-access-my-application-delegates-window-accessor-method-from-another-ob)